# How to map column and entity propery of different datatypes in entity framework code first

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-5

I am using Entity Framework 5 - Code first.

I have a database that I am connecting to that already exists for some time now (I did not create it).  There is a table called `T_Customers`.  It contains a list of all the customers.  It has the following structure (only partially shown):

```
Customer_id | numeric (5, 0) | auto increment | not null (not set as primary key)
FName | varchar(50) | not null
LName | varchar(50) | not null
```

My `Customer` class:

```
public class Customer : IEntity
{
     public int Id { get; set; }

     public string FirstName { get; set; }

     public string LastName { get; set; }
}
```

My `IEntity` interface:

```
public interface IEntity
{
     int Id { get; set; }
}
```

I have the following in my database context class:

```
public class DatabaseContext : DbContext
{
     public DatabaseContext(string connectionString)
          : base(connectionString)
     {
     }

     public DbSet<Customer> Customers { get; set; }

     protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
     {
          modelBuilder.Configurations.Add(new CustomerConfiguration());
     }

     public new DbSet<TEntity> Set<TEntity>()
          where TEntity : class, IEntity
     {
          return base.Set<TEntity>();
     }
}
```

My customer configuration class:

```
class CustomerConfiguration : EntityTypeConfiguration<Customer>
{
     internal CustomerConfiguration()
     {
          this.ToTable("T_Customers");
          this.Property(x => x.Id).HasColumnName("Customer_id");
          this.Property(x => x.FirstName).HasColumnName("FName");
          this.Property(x => x.LastName).HasColumnName("LName");
     }
}
```

I'm trying to be consistent in my entity declarations, I need all the IDs to be integers.  This customer ID is of type numeric in the database, and now I am running into issues when trying to return a list of all the customers.  How do I map from a database numeric type to a C# integer type?  I'm not changing my class's ID to nullable or decimal, my IDs are always non nullable and integer.  I also cannot change the database.

The error that I am getting is:

```
The 'Id' property on 'Customer' could not be set to a 'Decimal' value. 
You must set this property to a non-null value of type 'Int32'.
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Specify numeric type for column

```
Property(x => x.Id).HasColumnName("Customer_id").HasColumnType("numeric");
```

When generating database, it will create numeric column with precision `18,0`. But when you are mapping to existing database, it will work fine with `5,0` numeric column.

Comment: Thanks. What if I need a different precision that 18, 0? Is it better to stick with my precision of 5,0?

Comment: @BrendanVogt well, you said that you have already existing database, so your precision `5,0` will stay. If you will generate new database from code, then this column will have precision `18,0`. So, if you already have precision `5,0` you don't need to change anything. BTW integer could have value bigger than 99999, so it in mind.

Answer (score 4):

The simplest solution is to use another field that will be mapped to the database field, and the ID property will read/write to this field. Something like this:

```
public class Customer : IEntity
{
   public decimal CustomerID {get; set;}

   [NotMapped]
   public int Id 
   { 
      get { return (int)CustomerID; }
      set { CustomerID = (int)value; } 
   }

   public string FirstName { get; set; }

   public string LastName { get; set; }
}
```

Map this new field to the database field, using

```
this.Property(x => x.CustomerID).HasColumnName("Customer_id");
```

and the EF will use the customer id field, and your code could happily use the integer id field.

Answer (score 1):

In .Net Core you can also use System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema.ColumnAttribute to annotate the property with the underlying column type, e.g.,

```
    [Column(TypeName = "numeric(5, 0), not null")]
    public int Id { get; set; }
```

Or if the column is nullable:

```
    [Column(TypeName = "numeric(5, 0), null")]
    public int? Id { get; set; }
```

I prefer this to the accepted answer by @Sergey Berezovskiy, as you make the annotation actually on the model, not in elsewhere (in the DbContext).

The ColumnAttribute can also be used to map a property to a column with a different name, e.g.,

```
    [Column("Identifier", TypeName = "numeric(5, 0), not null")]
    public int Id { get; set; }
```

The ColumnAttribute may also work in the .Net Framework - I have not tested it.

Comment: Others prefer fluent mapping so the class model is *persistence ignorant*.

Answer (score -1):

Another option to work out what the code first should be is to the MS EF Powertools
http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/72a60b14-1581-4b9b-89f2-846072eff19d

You can add an empty project, right click, EF Reverse engineer code first from DB.

You often (not always) get a good start to the solution.
Did you try using decimal?

```
public class Customer : IEntity
{
 public decimal Id { get; set; }

 public string FirstName { get; set; }

 public string LastName { get; set; }
}
```

if you are concerned precision, you should add validation to the POCO.

There are also some interesting Anotation hacks you may like.
http://geekswithblogs.net/danemorgridge/archive/2010/12/20/ef4-code-first-control-unicode-and-decimal-precision-scale-with.aspx
good luck

Answer (score -2):

You can convert it to an int with:

```
 int myInt = Convert.Int32(numberFromDatabase);
```