# c# int value not selected correctly with linq query

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq

I've build a database using Entity Framework Code First.

I was trying to do a simple LINQ query ad display data of a table in a listbox, but an int value always results as 0.
So I tried to do a debug and in `XAML.CS` at this point:

```
var item = (from Item in db.Items
            select Item ).ToList();
```

My "Price" value is 0 when the entity is selected, but it should be 7

**EDIT**

**Item.cs**

```
    public int Price
    {
        get { return price; }
        set { price = value / 100; }
    }
```

Comment: What does the `Dish` class look like? What type is the `Price` column in the database?

Comment: it's an int, as I said in the question. Question edited and added my class

Comment: @CodeCaster but I don't think the problem is my class, since my data in the table is correct

Comment: 2/100 = 0 when you're doing `int` division. You should not have a getter and a setter that has different logic.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`set { price = value / 100; }`

There's your problem... I don't know what that's supposed to do, but remove the `/ 100` and it'll work.

`7 / 100` is `0`, since you're doing integer division.

If you want to show prices with decimal fractions, make the property and column a `decimal`.

Alternatively, if you're stuck with the `int` column for some reason, see [How to map column and entity propery of different datatypes in entity framework code first](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14812663/266143) how to do that:

```
// An int property to map to your database:
[Column("Price")]
public int PriceInt { get; set; }

// Use this property from code.
[NotMapped]   
public decimal Price 
{
    // Cast to decimal for decimal division.
    get { return (decimal)PriceInt / 100; }
    set { PriceInt = (int)(value * 100); }
}
```

Comment: My price is in pence, how can I show it in pounds then?

Comment: @Koosshh56 Convert it to double

Comment: @Koosshh56 two options basically: alter the column and property type, or map it yourself. See edit.

Comment: @cFrozenDeath don't use `double` for monetary data, use `decimal`.

Comment: @CodeCaster meant decimal, kinda sleepy, sorry.