# EF Object wrapper around a primitive type in DB/Domain model

Tags: c#, entity-framework, primitive-types

Suppose I have an Contact Table in my database, with a PhoneNumber column, which is a string, "+44123456789", for example.

In my domain model, I would normally have:

```
public class Contact {
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string PhoneNumber { get; set; }
}
```

So far so ordinary :) But now, I want to associate a bunch of non-DB logic with my PhoneNumber.

I can make a PhoneNumber object to hold all that logic, and make my `PhoneNumber` property be a `Number` object instead:

```
public class Contact {
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public Number PhoneNumber { get; set; }
}
public class Number{
    public string Number { get; set; }
    //... other logic, getter wrappers, etc. ...
}
```

But EF is going to interpret that as "Number is a new type with a separate table, and the Contact object should have a FK to a row in the Number table". Which I don't want - I want to keep the DB model the same. I can just do the conversion manually, in my C# but it's going to end up with a lot of boilerplate.

I would like to be able to tell EF, "I know this looks like an object, but trust me, it's a primitive. When you're storing it in the database, it's actually a primitive column. Please convert it to and from the primitive in the appropriate way (provided by the Number class, if necessary) whenever you interact with the database.

**Does this concept exist in EF?**

If so, what is the correct search term to find documentation of this?

Interested to know in either EF or EFCore.

Comment: +44.. you cant type to number. But this is what you want? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14812557/how-to-map-column-and-entity-propery-of-different-datatypes-in-entity-framework

Comment: or this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9613421/map-a-dictionary-in-entity-framework-code-first-approach

Comment: Looks like you are seeking for EF6 [Complex Type](https://entityframework.net/complex-type). The similar (but not exact) concept in EF Core is [Owned Entity Type](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/owned-entities)

Comment: @IvanStoev Yup, that's exactly the one. Do you want to post that as an answer, so that I can Accept it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Answer, courtesy of Ivan Stoev (See comments on question):

> Looks like the search term you are looking for is "Complex Type" in EF6.

Example search result: https://entityframework.net/complex-type

> In EFCore, a similar (but not identical) concept is "Owned Entity Type".

Example search result: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/owned-entities