# Mapping BigInt on model with INT

Tags: .net, sql-server, entity-framework, entity-framework-core

I have a table in a database that has a BigInt column. The data in this table will never exceed INT.

I can’t change the structure of the database because Legacy can break ...

Can I map BigInt to a model with INT?

I tried:

```
 var converter = new ValueConverter<int, long>(
            v => v,
            v => (int)v);
```

and call `HasConversion(converter)` in Fluent Api

But catch:

> System.InvalidCastException : Unable to cast object of type
>
> 'System.Int32' to type 'System.Int64'.

If i swap types:

> System.InvalidOperationException : Converter for model type 'long'
> cannot be used for 'DocumentRequest.Id' because its type is 'int'.

=> first option is valid

I would do in the Int64 model, but in the main table there can be ID BigInt, and in the children the Foreign Key link as INT => mapping does not work ...

Damn bd...

Comment: Perhaps the code can utilize an `int` property on the model that is "unmapped", but performs the conversion in its `get`/`set`, similar to this:
 https://stackoverflow.com/a/14812663/3390788

Answer (score 1):

This is a quirk of C#.  You can't actually cast between these types, but they have [Cast Operators](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/type-testing-and-cast#cast-operator-) to perform the conversion.  Eg

```
    long l = 0;
    Int32 i = (Int32)l; //works

    Int32 i2 = (Int32)(object)l; //fails System.InvalidCastException: 'Unable to cast object of type 'System.Int64' to type 'System.Int32'.'
```

The fix is simply to use Convert instead of the a C# cast.  EG

```
    var converter = new ValueConverter<int, long>(
            i => Convert.ToInt64(i),
            l => Convert.ToInt32(l));
```